# Compilation error when subscription callback's input is of certain type

Tags: ros2

I did an experiment where I tried all combinations of const, &, and SharedPtr as the input to the subscription callback. The message type is `nav_msgs::msg::Odometry` and the results are at the bottom of the code snippet.

```
#include "rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp"
#include "nav_msgs/msg/odometry.hpp"

class SubToSharedPtr : public rclcpp::Node
{
public:
    SubToSharedPtr()
    : Node("sub_to_shared_ptr_node")
    {
        odom_sub_ = this->create_subscription<nav_msgs::msg::Odometry>(
            "odom", rclcpp::SystemDefaultsQoS(),
            std::bind(&SubToSharedPtr::odomCb, this, std::placeholders::_1)
        );
    }

private:
    rclcpp::Subscription<nav_msgs::msg::Odometry>::SharedPtr odom_sub_;

    void odomCb(const nav_msgs::msg::Odometry& msg)
    {

    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    rclcpp::init(argc, argv);
    auto node = std::make_shared<SubToSharedPtr>();
    rclcpp::spin(node);
    rclcpp::shutdown();
    return 0;
}

// const SharedPtr& - doesn't work
// const SharedPtr - works
// SharedPtr - works
// SharedPtr& - doesn't work
// const & - works
// const - works
// & - doesn't work
// nothing - works
```

It seems like there is an important implication to this pattern (maybe something to do with ownership?). For example, all the ones with & doesn't work except for const & maybe because even though you are getting the actual variable (not a copy) you are promising not to change it, which is why it's acceptable.

Does anyone have an explanation for why this pattern exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that the implication to the pattern does have to do with ownership. I'll summarize here, but there is a much more thorough explanation of the guidelines in [Herb Sutter's GoTW #91: Smart Pointer Parameters](https://herbsutter.com/2013/06/05/gotw-91-solution-smart-pointer-parameters/)

The relevant section that the ROS 2 callbacks are enforcing are:

> Guideline: Don’t pass a smart pointer as a function parameter unless you want to use or manipulate the smart pointer itself, such as to share or transfer ownership.

> Guideline: Prefer passing objects by value, *, or &, not by smart pointer.

The new set of signatures are trying to be much more explicit about ownership.  While the ownership may not be important in a single-producer, single-consumer situation, there are more complex applications.  This is especially important in the case of *intraprocess communications* where the messages are held in an internal buffer and only distributed based on the signatures of the subscriptions.  For more information on the implications on *intraprocess comms*, consult the [Intraprocess Communications Design Doc](https://design.ros2.org/articles/intraprocess_communications.html).   The most relevant section is *Number of message copies*, which has a table comparing various signatures.

Generally the signatures should be thought of as follows:

- `const Msg &` - immutable, no ownership
- `unique_ptr<Msg>` - mutable and takes ownership
- `shared_ptr<const Msg>` - immutable, but allows subscription to share ownership (by copying into member)
- `const shared_ptr<const Msg> &` - immutable, but allows subscription to share ownership (by copying into member)
- `shared_ptr<Msg>` - deprecated.  It's potentially unsafe if multiple subscriptions take the same message.

Finally, for a full enumeration of all of the available subscription types, it's best to consult the `AnySubscriptionCallbackPossibleTypes` structure in `rclcpp`: https://github.com/ros2/rclcpp/blob/rolling/rclcpp/include/rclcpp/any_subscription_callback.hpp#L57